# Is it possible to access struct members using variables in brackets in C?

Tags: c, struct, cs50

I´m working on a CS50 task where I should create image filters. I have written the code, it works and passes all tests. However part of the code in my blur filter is not well designed in my view. I have copy-pasted a code chunk three times instead of looping over it. I have tried looping it, but could not figure it out. Basically want to access struct members dynamically.

**The struct:**

```
typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

**The image created from the struct:**

```
RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]
```

As you see below I have three code chunks that are almost the same in the loop. The difference is the name of the struct member "rgbtRed", "rgbtGreen" & "rgbtBlue".

```
for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
{
    // array to put our values in
    int sqr[] = { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 };
    int tempSum = 0;

    if (k == 0)
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            sqr[0] = j > 0 ? image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed : -1;
            sqr[1] = image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed;
            sqr[2] = j < width - 1 ? image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed : -1;
        }

        sqr[3] = j > 0 ? image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed : -1;
        sqr[4] = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
        sqr[5] = j < width - 1 ? image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed : -1;

        if (i < (height - 1))
        {
            sqr[6] = j > 0 ? image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed : -1;
            sqr[7] = image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed;
            sqr[8] = j < width - 1 ? image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed : -1;
        }
    }
    else if (k == 1)
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            sqr[0] = j > 0 ? image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen : -1;
            sqr[1] = image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen;
            sqr[2] = j < width - 1 ? image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen : -1;
        }

        sqr[3] = j > 0 ? image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen : -1;
        sqr[4] = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
        sqr[5] = j < width - 1 ? image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen : -1;

        if (i < (height - 1))
        {
            sqr[6] = j > 0 ? image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen : -1;
            sqr[7] = image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen;
            sqr[8] = j < width - 1 ? image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen : -1;
        }
    }
    else if (k == 2)
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            sqr[0] = j > 0 ? image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue : -1;
            sqr[1] = image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue;
            sqr[2] = j < width - 1 ? image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue : -1;
        }

        sqr[3] = j > 0 ? image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue : -1;
        sqr[4] = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        sqr[5] = j < width - 1 ? image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue : -1;

        if (i < (height - 1))
        {
            sqr[6] = j > 0 ? image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue : -1;
            sqr[7] = image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue;
            sqr[8] = j < width - 1 ? image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue : -1;
        }
    }

    // sum temp.
    float divider = 0.0;
    for (int l = 0; l < 9; l++)
    {
        if (sqr[l] >= 0 && sqr[l] <= 255)
        {
            tempSum = tempSum + sqr[l];
            divider++;
        }
    }

    // calulate average color for each
    avgRGB[k] = round(tempSum / divider);
}
```

I did try to create dynamic names as variables using:

```
if (k == 0)
{
  char *color = "rgbtRed";
} else if (k == 1)
  char...
```

And then using that variable as dynamic name to access the struct member with brackets [] instead of (.) as follows:

```
...image[i][j][color];
```

However that did not work and as I´m new to learning C I would much appreciate some guidance to improve my code.

All the best!

Comment: Just a sidenote: `sqr[l] >= 0` Value 0 is perfectly valid. If you use `-1` as "invalid" marker, you should check for this value, not some other values as well.

Comment: What you want to do is not possible. Struct members are not an array. C does not treat structs as sets of key/value pairs.

Comment: Why do you need `__attribute__((__packed__))` when you only have 3 bytes in the `struct`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, to make sure that the compiler won't stick any padding bytes. Like rounding it to 4 bytes.

Comment: @tstanisl Is there even a compiler around that both understands `__attribute__((__packed__))` and would potentially add padding bytes? It's perfectly aligned without padding so it would seem odd.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, probably you are right. This kind of compiler would be odd. A static assert should be enough. `_Static_assert(sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) == 3, "Oops");`

Comment: You can get rid of much of the redundant code by treating all three components simultaneously insead of sequentially: (1) gather the data and count of pixels needed for the square; (2) calculate the average. [See here](https://pastebin.com/ydBHuyPA) (not tested).

Answer (score 2):

You could make `RBGTRIPLE` a union of the anonymous struct combined with 3-element array.

```
typedef union {
  struct {
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
  } __attribute__((__packed__))
  BYTE rbgt[3];
} RGBTRIPLE;
```

Now you can access individual components of the image as `image[y][x].rgbt[1]` rather than `image[y][x].rgbtGreen`.

Now you can replace repetitive chain of `if (k == ...) { ... } else` with a single case:

```
if (i > 0) {
            sqr[0] = j > 0 ? image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbt[k] : -1;
            sqr[1] = image[i - 1][j].rgbt[k];
            sqr[2] = j < width - 1 ? image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbt[k] : -1;
}

sqr[3] = j > 0 ? image[i][j - 1].rgbt[k] : -1;
sqr[4] = image[i][j].rgbt[k];
sqr[5] = j < width - 1 ? image[i][j + 1].rgbt[k] : -1;

if (i < (height - 1)) {
            sqr[6] = j > 0 ? image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbt[k] : -1;
            sqr[7] = image[i + 1][j].rgbt[k];
            sqr[8] = j < width - 1 ? image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbt[k] : -1;
}
```

Comment: Shorter names? He is doing well!!!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, that looks like the solution I was aiming for. But I forgot to mention in my question that the struct was provided as part of the course code and I do not think that part should be edited.

Comment: @Beorn, you could try casting `image` to 3d array. `BYTE (*arr)[width][3] = (void*)image;`. This violates strict aliasing rule though it will likely work because `BYTE` (`unsigned char`?) can alias everything

Comment: @Beorn no one can stop you from embedding that struct from the CS50 course into a union as shown above. You don't need to touch the course material.

Comment: @SupportUkraine, OP was asking about accessing the struct via `[]` operator. Feel free to post your own answer

Comment: @SupportUkraine, yes, the (in)famous XY problem. Though the problem of accessing a struct via `[]` is quite common. Especially, in graphics where `mat4x4` or `vec3` types are heavily used.

Comment: @tstanisl: Re “This violates strict aliasing rule though” and “BYTE (unsigned char?) can alias everything”: The C standard’s aliasing rule says character types can alias any object. So accessing an object with a character type does **not** violate the aliasing rule.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I was considering aliasing between `BYTE[3]` and `RGBTRIPLE`. AFAIK, C standard is quite vague about it.